# sql: BETWEEN v1 AND v2

Tags: sql-server, between, syntactic-sugar

Is there a difference in the order of v1 and v2 in a BETWEEN query on SQL Server?

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE col BETWEEN v1 AND v2
```

currently I don’t get any results if v1 is bigger than v2. Is this only syntactic sugar for

```
col >= v1 AND col <= v2
```

or does it really take all values between the two? on my current observations I guess it’s the first case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQL Server 2008:

```
select 1 
where 5 between 1 and 7
```

1 result

```
select 1 
where 5 between 7 and 1
```

0 results

Based on these results, and the [Postgre Docs](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/postgresql/vol1/ComparisonOperators.html)  I would hypothesize that the ANSI Standard is as follows (although I can't find that doc).

```
a between x and y
==
a >= x AND a <= y
```

UPDATE:

The SQL-92 spec says (quote):

```
"X BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "X>=Y AND X<=Z"
```

Comment: And check out "select 1 where 7 between 7 and 1" - awesome!

Comment: the examples are not syntactically valid in MySQL

Comment: @törzsmókus maybe because it was an SQL Server question

Answer (score 11):

Yes! The order of the arguments in the BETWEEN predicate matter.
And, yes, this is [mostly] syntactic sugar for the AND-ed comparison form.

The "mostly", above comes from the fact that while ***logically equivalent***, the two expressions may (probably in the past...) receive a distinct query plan on some SQL servers.  It is a safe guess that most servers, nowadays, provide an optimal handling of this type of filter, regardless of its form.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right, is it only syntactic sugar for the construct you mentioned.