# How to show records that falls on the date-range using if statement

Tags: php, mysql, date, if-statement, date-range

I want to display all the records during August of the current year up to December of the current year. While it will not display on January up to June, Instead the Records of January up to June will be displayed. 
How will I catch the date using IF statement?

Here is my code:

```
            $year = date("Y");
            $sem1_start = date("M-d-Y", strtotime("August, 01".$year));
            $sem1_end = date("M-d-Y", strtotime("December, 31".$year));

            $sem2_start = date("M-d-Y", strtotime("January, 01".$year));
            $sem2_end = date("M-d-Y", strtotime("June, 15".$year));

            //sample date from database
            $date = '2015-10-15';
            $date2 = date("M-d-Y", strtotime($date));


            if($date2 >= $sem1_s && $date2 <= $sem1_e){
                //Display all records
            }
            else if($date2 >= $sem2_s && $date2 <= $sem2_e){
                 //Display all records
            }
```

I wanted to automatically display the records of the current semester (August-December) and when January comes, it will hide the records but will display the records of the second semester which is January up to June.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter your sql result with the between statement. Something like

$query = "select * from db_table where datefield BETWEEN $startdate and $enddate order by datefield asc;

That way your results will always fall in range and are sorted to boot

Comment: better do not use the between statement. Is the start date include? is the end date included? Better use `datefield > $startdate and datefield < $enddate `

Comment: Not so. Now you create two internal check on non integer fields, while otherwise you would use a standard build in function which is highly optimized for these cases. It will work though. But with large datasets it might be considerable slower.

Comment: Not so. have a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692593/between-operator-vs-and-is-there-a-performance-difference)

Comment: Maybe so. But that is with integer values. We are now taking about date values, which are basically formatted strings if you are not using timestamps. String searches are always slower then integer searches.

Comment: datefield > $startdate and datefield < $enddate, I did this but It can't catch the dates.. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I think, in the database I have a field to save valuable time

```
$time = time();
```

When I want to search from August of the current year to March 12 of the current year I will do the following

```
$timeSearchStart = strtotime(date('Y') . '-8-1 00:00:00');
$timeSearchEnd = strtotime(date('Y') . '-12-31 23:59:59');
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `fieldSaveTime` > '" . $timeSearchStart . "' && `fieldSaveTime` < '" . $timeSearchEnd  . "'";
```

Comment: I use this $timeSearchStart = strtotime(date('Y') . '-8-1 00:00:00'); to assign the date but my problem is my IF statement can't catch the date on my database

Comment: @its.L.A you must use the time() function to save time in fieldSaveTime
or you change same it