# Using BETWEEN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Whenever you write a query where you need to filter out rows on a range of values - then should I use the `BETWEEN` clause or `<=` and `>=` ?

Which one is better in performance?

Comment: They're identical in terms of performance - if a suitable index is present, SQL Server will do a range scan in both cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL : BETWEEN vs <= and >=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630239/sql-between-vs-and)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither.  They create exactly the same execution plan.

The times where I use them depends not on performance, but on the data.

If the data are Discrete Values, then I use `BETWEEN`...

- `x BETWEEN 0 AND 9`

But if the data are Continuous Values, then that doesn't work so well...

- `x BETWEEN 0.000 AND 9.999999999999999999`

Instead, I use `>= AND <`...

- `x >= 0 AND x < 10`

Interestingly, however, the `>= AND <` technique actually works for ***both*** Continuous and Discrete data types.  So, in general, I rarely use `BETWEEN` at all.

Answer (score 4):

Also, don't use `BETWEEN` for date/time range queries.

What does the following really mean?

```
BETWEEN '20120201' AND '20120229'
```

Some people think that means get me the all the data from February, including all of the data anytime on February 29th. The above gets translated to:

```
BETWEEN '20120201 00:00:00.000' AND '20120229 00:00:00.000'
```

So if there is data on the 29th any time after midnight, your report is going to be incomplete.

People also try to be clever and pick the "end" of the day:

```
BETWEEN '00:00:00.000' AND '23:59:59.997'
```

That works if the data type is `datetime`. If it is `smalldatetime` the end of the range gets rounded up, and you may include data from the next day that you didn't mean to. If it's `datetime2` you might actually miss a small portion of data that happened in the last 2+ milliseconds of the day. In most cases statistically irrelevant, but if the query is wrong, the query is wrong.

So for date range queries I always strongly recommend using an open-ended range, e.g. to report on the month of February the `WHERE` clause would say "on or after February 1st, and before March 1st" as follows:

```
WHERE date_col >= '20120201' AND date_col < '20120301'
```

`BETWEEN` can work as expected using the `date` type only, but I still prefer an open-ended range in queries because later someone may change that underlying data type to allow it to include time.

I blogged a lot more details here:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Not to mention that `20120229` is a perfectly cromulent date, but `20110229` and `20130229` are not.  Using `>= AND <` means that you never even need to use that date when looking at monthly groupings.

Comment: @Dems yep, I chose that date on purpose. Should have extrapolated more use out of it. :-)