# Is there a difference in terms of precision when comparing two dates using '=<' and '>=' instead of using 'between'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query that provides the records displayed on a report and noticed that the previous developer used '=<' and '>=' to compare two datetimes that are parameters of said query. These parameters are passed as strings and are not converted into datetime objects.
I noticed that, in the query results, I'm missing data from about two days.
I'd like to know if there is any difference in precision when comparing these datetimes using '=<' and '>=' instead of using 'between' (which could be what is causing the loss of data in the results).

For completeness, here is a simple example of the current comparison used:

```
Declare @DateTo varchar(max) = '2013-07-29'
Declare @DateFrom varchar(max) = '2013-07-07'

SELECT * FROM Records WHERE Date =< @DateTo AND Date >= @DateFrom
```

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630239/sql-between-vs-and

Comment: No, there is no precision loss. What is your actual problem?

Comment: I was losing data on the query results and I wasn't sure if the way the comparison was made had any influence.

Comment: If your `Date` column is of `Datetime` type and you have records on `2013-07-29` during the day, this query will not fetch them and neither would `BETWEEN`. You should use `< '2013-07-30'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(There is no `=<` operator in SQL, you mean the `<=` operator.)

The `between` operator compares the values inclusively, so it's the same as using the `<=` and `>=` operators.

If the values are just a date, you can use inclusive values like that. If they also contain a time component, you should consider using an exclusive higher limit. That way you can query different ranges without overlap, e.g. the value `2013-07-30 00:00:00.000` will not be included both in the ranges `2013-07-07 to 2013-07-30` and `2013-07-30 to 2013-08-02`. The expression `Date < '2013-07-30'` will include all values up to `2013-07-29 23:59:59.999` but not `2013-07-30 00:00:00.000`.

Example:

```
Declare @DateTo varchar(max) = '2013-07-30' -- the day after the range
Declare @DateFrom varchar(max) = '2013-07-07'

SELECT * FROM Records WHERE Date < @DateTo AND Date >= @DateFrom
```