# How to filter a DateTime column by Date

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, datetime

My database is SQL Server 2008 and I have a query which returns some details filtered by date. In the WHERE close of the query I have something like this

```
WHERE (CONVERT (DATE, Attendance.in_time) = @inDate)
```

**NOTE** : `Attendance.in_time` is a `DateTime` column

Here I'm trying to get the date part only from `in_time` and to compare it with `@inDate` parameter in .net.

My problem is, in .NET we cant have only the data part of a DateTime. One option is to convert it to a string as follows

```
var inDate = InTime.Date.ToString("d");
```

But now the problem is Date and String cannot be compared in the SQL query?

Can anyone provide a solution?

EDIT : As requested in comments I'm showing full query here ...

```
 public List<IAttendance> ShowAttendance(DateTime InDate, string pid, List<IAttendance> list)
        {
            string selectStatement = "SELECT Employee.Emp_ID, Employee.Initials + ' ' + Employee.Surname AS Name, Attendance.in_time, Attendance.out_time, Attendance.shift "+
                                     "FROM Attendance INNER JOIN Employee ON Attendance.EID = Employee.Emp_ID "+
                                     "WHERE (CONVERT (DATE, Attendance.in_time) = @inDate) AND (Attendance.PID = @pid) ";

//

}
```

Comment: Better convert that string to date in SQL. WHERE (CONVERT (DATE, Attendance.in_time) = convert(date,@inDate))

Comment: @Azar, But I'm doing the comparison in application not in SQL Server!

Comment: Can you show the whole code around that convert?

Comment: Create a new DateTime variable from the year, month, and day components of inTime and do your comparisons to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your SQL query to exploit the [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) clause

```
 public List<IAttendance> ShowAttendance(DateTime InDate, string pid, List<IAttendance> list)
 {
    string selectStatement = "SELECT Employee.Emp_ID, Employee.Initials + ' '" + 
                             "Employee.Surname AS Name, Attendance.in_time, " + 
                             "Attendance.out_time, Attendance.shift " +
                             "FROM Attendance INNER JOIN Employee " + 
                             "ON Attendance.EID = Employee.Emp_ID " +
                             "WHERE (Attendance.in_time BETWEEN @inDate AND @endDate) " + 
                             "AND Attendance.PID = @pid";
    ......
 }
```

and pass two parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inDate", InDate.Date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", InDate.Date.AddMinutes(1439));
.....
```

In this way, the returned records belogs to the same day without the need of complex conversions on the SQL Server side.

As pointed out in the comments below, if there are some values stored after 23.59 you could use `AddSeconds(86399)` instead of `AddMinutes(1439)` to enclose also these values. And if you need also milliseconds precision due to the nature of DateTime sql type then

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", InDate.Date.AddSeconds(86399).AddMilliseconds(999));
```

Again, due to some comments below. Probably the best option is to use

"WHERE (Attendance.in_time >= @inDate AND Attendance.in_time < @endDate) "

with the parameters defined as

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inDate", InDate.Date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", InDate.Date.AddDay(1));
```

Comment: In parameter section it should be InDate.Date and InDate.Date.AddMinutes(1439)). Isn't it?

Comment: when operating with datetimes in that way, you should NEVER use between. In this case you will miss all rows the last minute of the day

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Well you are correct of course, but if there are also seconds stored just `AddSeconds(86399)` could resolve the problem. Or not?

Comment: @steve that will not solve the problem for milliseconds. Just use column >= fromvalue and column < tovalue

Comment: if you add your current calculation to a datetime you get the next day, due to a feature in datetime you need to add 997 milliseconds. Not really readable. We are back where we started - NEVER use between when operating with datetime intervals. Also things could change the day the system undergo an upgrade to datetime2

Comment: Well, after a bit of [searching around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630239/sql-between-vs-and) and for the purpose of this discussion I could agree with you. However I think we could agree also that the problem for the poster is that he/she needs two values to search for. A lower bound and an upper bound. This could be given also with Greater Than `>=` and Less Than `<=`

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution**:  Instead of changing your SQL syntax, just pass the `InDate.Today` as the parameter.

A DateTime at 12:00 am is equal to a Date on the same day.

```
DECLARE @X DATETIME 
DECLARE @Y DATE

SET @Y = '12/31/2010'
SET @X = '12/31/2010 12:00:00 am'

IF @X = @Y  PRINT 'ok'  -- prints ok

SET @X = '12/31/2010 12:00:01 am'

IF @X != @Y  PRINT 'bad'  -- prints bad
```

Answer (score 1):

I do the comparision this way

```
create  function [dbo].[DateOnly](@DateTime DateTime)
-- Returns @DateTime at midnight; i.e., it removes the time portion of a DateTime value.
returns datetime
as
    begin
    return dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,@DateTime))
    end
```

and then i compare dates this way

```
WHERE dbo.dateonly(Attendance.in_time) = dbo.dateonly(@inDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

define `inTime` like this:

```
var inDate = InTime.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Now is it not a String?

Answer (score 0):

I would break it up into YYYY MM DD
In SQL is it

```
YEAR(Attendance.in_time) 
MONTH(Attendance.in_time)
DAY(Attendance.in_time)
```

In .NET it is properties

```
Year
Month
Day
```

[DateTime Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

All 6 are Int