# Using PHP Operators for selecting data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to select some specific arrays from my mysql database, I used this:

```
 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`title`, `author`, `publication`, `series`, `price`, `image`, `description`, `quantity`, `status` FROM `books` WHERE  `id` >= '$p1' AND `id` =< '$p2'  ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

$p1 and $p2 are multiples of 5. for example: 0 and 5, 5 and 10, 10 and 15;
but using this code, I faced this error not knowing how to fix it!

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=< '15' ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1
```

Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: `=<` is an invalid operator in PHP and in SQL (and indeed in most programming languages); you mean `<=`

Comment: Use `BETWEEN` in your SQL statement instead of defining the range using two value limitations, as seen here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630239/sql-between-vs-and) Also make sure your PHP-vars are sanitized before just pasting in your SQL-statement, because of SQL-injection hazard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mark Baker stated in his comment to you it is an invalid operator in PHP

Change this

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`title`, `author`, `publication`, `series`, `price`, `image`, `description`, `quantity`, `status` FROM `books` WHERE  `id` >= '$p1' AND `id` =< '$p2'  ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

To this

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`title`, `author`, `publication`, `series`, `price`, `image`, `description`, `quantity`, `status` FROM `books` WHERE  `id` >= '$p1' AND `id` <= '$p2'  ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank You Joshua
Just a very small mistake!
=< and <=
:)

Comment: @Kaarmoolak You are Welcome, Looks like everyone jumped at this one at the same time. Everyone have the right answer. So thanks to everyone not just me :P

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`title`, `author`, `publication`, `series`, `price`, `image`, `description`, `quantity`, `status` FROM `books` WHERE  `id` >= '$p1' AND `id` <= '$p2'  ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

The operator `=<` doesn't exist in SQL.

Also, you can see a list of all the comparison operators here: http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqopr.htm#i1004774

Answer (score 0):

replace your query wit this..

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`title`, `author`, `publication`, `series`, `price`, `image`, `description`, `quantity`, `status` FROM `books` WHERE  `id` >= '$p1' AND `id` <= '$p2'  ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE  id >= '$p1' AND id <= '$p2'  ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

**Don't use** ` in php code

**And** `=<` should define as `<=`.

**Improvements**

use `SELECT *` without giving all database fields

> If I copy your code to my IDE, it shows all **the syntax Errors**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem remains on your **less than or equal** operator. It should be (<=). So your query will be:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`title`, `author`, `publication`, `series`, `price`, `image`, `description`, `quantity`, `status` FROM `books` WHERE  `id` >= '$p1' AND `id` <= '$p2'  ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Alternately you can use **BETWEEN** for range selection:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`title`, `author`, `publication`, `series`, `price`, `image`, `description`, `quantity`, `status` FROM `books` WHERE  `id` BETWEEN '$p1' AND '$p2'  ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated the =< operator is incorrect and that is likely the cause of the error but the search of less than / greater than can be simplified using 'between'

```
$sql="select 
            `id`, `title`, `author`, `publication`, `series`, `price`, `image`, `description`, `quantity`, `status` 
                from `books` 
                where  `id` between $p1 and $p2 
                order by id desc;";

$result2 = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( mysql_error() );
```