# SQL Query Performance with BETWEEN AND Vs GTE/LTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

In **SQL** we have these 2 function to retrieve data in range, I am using this on datetime field and trying to retrieve data for last 4 years.

Just wanted to confirm which is better in terms of query performance out of **BETWEEN...AND** or     **>=** .

My final result row count is 200000 and it is has grouping, overall execution time is 3 minutes.

Comment: No difference, same thing is executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL : BETWEEN vs <= and >=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630239/sql-between-vs-and)

Comment: 2 UDFs returning data for 4 years, grouping of 200K records... And this led you to the question about `>=` and `between`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a slight difference `BETWEEN` and regular operators.

`BETWEEN` is inclusive, meaning the expression `WHERE COL BETWEEN 200 AND 500` is equivalent to writing 
`WHERE COL >=200 AND COL < 501` (or <=)

On the other hand, the operators `<` and `>`and `=` are exclusive.

Its a distinction that should be kept in mind.

[BETWEEN - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)