# Query records between business years

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Business starts on first October of every year. I need two queries, one which returns all records for current business year and the other returns all records for previous business year. Leap year is not important in this case.

I have written:

```
strSql1 = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE DateDiff('d', 
[OrderDate], [YearStart])<=365 ORDER BY [OrderDate] ASC"

Me.frmCurrentYear.Form.RecordSource = strSql1

strSql2 = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE DateDiff('d', [OrderDate], 
[YearStart])>365 AND DateDiff('d', [PurchaseDate],[YearStart]<=730) ORDER BY 
[OrderDate] ASC"

Me.frmPreviousYear.Form.RecordSource = strSql2
```

Questions:

1. From my code, I will have to add a `YearStart` field to my table. Is there a way to avoid this?
2. Would using `BETWEEN` be a more efficient way?

With thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *DateSerial* for such tasks:
For the year starting `yyyy/10/01`, the current business year records would be:

```vb
strSql1 = "SELECT * FROM Orders " & _
"WHERE DateDiff('m', [OrderDate], DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 1)) Between 3 And -9 " & _
"ORDER BY [OrderDate] ASC"
```

Records for previous business year would then be:

```vb
strSql2 = "SELECT * FROM Orders " & _
"WHERE DateDiff('m', [OrderDate], DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, 1, 1)) Between 3 And -9 " & _
"ORDER BY [OrderDate] ASC"
```

Comment: can you explain a bit please? On w3schools `DateDiff('m', '1/10/2019', DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 1));` gives me 12 while
`DateDiff('m', '1/10/2017', DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, 1, 1));` gives 24 and have no idea where the Between -3 and 9 comes in.

Comment: It specifies the possible difference in calendar months between OrderDate and the latest  New Year (or that before).

Comment: I see, I have added a parenthesis to finish up  the `DateDiff()` function. Sometimes the business starts in September would this also be valid?

Comment: Yes. That would be `Between -4 And 8`.

Answer (score 0):

1- You can always calculate something like if month is oct ,nov or dec then current year else previous year.

```
case when Month(GetDate()) >=10 then Cast('10-01'+Cast(Year(GetDate() as Varchar(5)) as date)
     when Month(GetDate()) <10 then Cast('10-01'+Cast(Year(GetDate())-1 as varcher(5)) as date) 
END as YearStart
```

2- [SQL : BETWEEN vs <= and >=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630239/sql-between-vs-and)

Answer (score 0):

The current business year is defined as the year when you add three months:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE YEAR(DATEADD("m", 3, YEAR(OrderDate))) = YEAR(DATE())
```

And for the previous year:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE YEAR(DATEADD("m", 3, YEAR(OrderDate))) = YEAR(DATE()) - 1
```

This assumes that Jan - Dep 2020 are in year "2020" and the last three months are in year "2021".