# Difference between ranging SQL join types (inequality operators vs BETWEEN)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have inherited some SQL code that leaves me a bit uneasy:

`FROM table AS x LEFT JOIN table AS y ON y.date_1 <= x.date AND y.date_2 >= x.date`

And I am more accustomed to something like:

`FROM table AS x LEFT JOIN table AS y ON x.date BETWEEN y.date_1 AND y.date_2`

I didn't see a difference in the execution plan. Is one more preferred or optimal compared to the other?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Execution plans are product specific.)

Comment: I'm of the opinion that `JOIN` conditions should **only** be tuple-equality (aka equi-joins), not range-comparisons - because a JOIN often corresponds to an FK constraint which is most-performant when only performing set-membership checks (don't forget to ensure you have indexes for each FK in your DB) - range comparisons like those are better suited for the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I say KISS. Keep it simple, use BETWEEN.

Comment: @Dai, I say the opposite, use ON for _all_ multi-table conditions (i.e. all JOIN conditions) Keep WHERE for regular one-table filtering.

Comment: @jarlh on the contrary: I _utterly despise_ the `BETWEEN` operator because it _complicates_ having to think about `date` vs `datetime` types and values - and because it's inclusive-upper-bound (not exclusive-upper-bound) it just makes everything awful.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using BigQuery

Comment: It's convenient that you chose to ask this question in the context of an outer join, since there is a significant difference in functional meaning when we move logic between an `ON` clause and a `WHERE` clause when dealing with an outer join. With an inner join, that's not an issue.  The 'outer' behavior applies only to the corresponding `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause... at least in terms of an ansi join.

Comment: I'm an idiot. It's an inner join not a left join. What does that change?

Comment: It doesn't really change your question.  But some comments about `ON` vs `WHERE` might lead us to think about join type.  For your question, the expressions are logically equivalent.  It's reasonable to expect the same plan, although there's no guarantee for any specific DB implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are right that they don't have differences. They only differ on how you are going to use `Comparison Operators` and `BETWEEN`. Comparison operators are relational where you compare two values, and BETWEEN is when you want to get the values on your given range.

From your example code above, BETWEEN is more preferred since it is shorter and less complex.

I also found an answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630239/sql-between-vs-and).

Note: Inequality operator is `!=`, although it is also included in comparison operators.