# AGE [1, 2, 3] vs. AGE BETWEEN 1 AND 3

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an InnoDB table and an index on `age` column just like this

```
   CREATE TABLE Person (

      ....
      age int(11) not null;
      key (age);
      ....
   ) engine=InnoDB;
```

I just want to know the real things behind these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age IN [1, 2, 3];
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
```

As what I've learnt, the first one MySQL will use the index on column age while the second one it can't use. Is it? Which is better for performance?

Comment: Use [`explain`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to find out exactly how the database is processing these in your specific case.

Comment: also see [sql: BETWEEN v1 AND v2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1572840/112968)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both queries will use an index.

Query A will translated to:

```
select * from person where age = 1 or age = 2 or age 3;
```

Query B will translate to

```
select * from person where age >= 1 and age <= 3;
```

So query A will do 3 tests using OR.
Query B will do 2 tests using AND.

**Query B is faster.**

In general, queries using `AND` are faster than queries using `OR`.
Also Query B is doing fewer tests and because it's testing a range it can more easily exclude results that it does not want.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have MySQL server installed on my netbook right now but sticking a `EXPLAIN` statement might give you the answer you are looking for:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age IN [1, 2, 3];
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find the answers to this StackOverflow question helpful:

[MYSQL OR vs IN [vs BETWEEN] performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782915/mysql-or-vs-in-performance)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age IN [1, 2, 3];
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age = 1 OR age = 2 OR age 3
```

whereas

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age >= 1 AND age <= 3
```

use `EXPLAIN` to see the actual execution plan for the different forms of the queries. i would be surprised too see mysql not using an index with `BETWEEN`.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age IN [1,2,3];
```

should give you an exact answer for your exact query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age >= 1 AND age <= 3
```

is faster than `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age BETWEEN 1 AND 3;` and `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Person WHERE age IN [1,2,3];`

you can try with 1 million record of mysql db.